# Slow EF Core Performance when uploaded to Azure

Tags: database, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm currently on EFCore 3.0. I have a query that fetch records from database that run within one second in localhost but more than 10 seconds when on Azure Web Service.

The code I written is to retrieve all user posts from database based on their connections, similar idea like a social wall posts. The postheaders first being retrieved as IQueryable and then process into IEnumerable based on the page number and page size.

There are more than hundreds of record in PostHeaders. Is this the right way to handle data querying in EFCore?

Here is my EF code to retrieve posts from database :

```
public async Task<PagedList<PostHeader>> GetPosts(int socialProfileId, SocialPostHeaderParams socialPostHeaderParams)
    {
        List<int> userConnectionIds = await _context.SocialConnections
            .Where(sc => sc.FirstSUPId == socialProfileId && sc.Status == "Connected")
            .Select(sc => sc.SecondSUPId)
            .ToListAsync();

        userConnectionIds.Add(socialProfileId);


        IQueryable<PostHeader> postHeadersToReturn = _context.PostHeaders
            .Include(u => u.SocialUserProfile)
                .ThenInclude(sup => sup.SocialAlbums)
                    .ThenInclude(sa => sa.SocialPhotos)
            .Include(ps => ps.PostStatus)
                .ThenInclude(psp => psp.PostPictures)
            .Include(pc => pc.PostComments)
            .Include(ph => ph.PostHearts)
            .Where(ph => (userConnectionIds.Contains(ph.CreatedBySUPId) && ph.SocialGroupId == 0 && ph.SocialPageId == 0 && ph.Enabled))
            .OrderByDescending(ph => ph.Created)
            .AsQueryable();

        return await PagedList<PostHeader>.CreateAsync(postHeadersToReturn, socialPostHeaderParams.PageNumber, socialPostHeaderParams.PageSize);
    }


public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber -1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

        return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
```

Comment: Previously, the database run on the same machine as the client, serving only that single client. Now, it runs on a throttled VM on a host that serves 100 other customers, on another network, with throttled network bandwidth. Any of those things could reduce performance. Frankly, even if you deployed to an on-prem server you would see delays simply because your network is slower than in-memory access on the same machine

Comment: 1 sec is way too much for a local connection too. The paging code is inefficient and essentially executes the query *multiple* times. That `CountAsync()` runs on top of a query that joins way more tables than needed to determine how many `PostHeaders` there are. You could get that number with a far simpler, far faster query. There's no need to execute that for *every* page either.

Comment: `more than hundreds of record` that's no data at all. SQL Server is built to work with billions of rows and TBs of data on a single machine. 100s of records are so few they can all be kept in a CPU's cache. So the code is clearly far too slow already.

Comment: If you use SQL Server, use the Activity Monitor or Extended Events to check what the query does, what its execution plan looks like, whether there are any missing indexes or operations that prevent the use of indexes